# Loop through an object if property does not always exist or is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I want to build a table in Raect with a sorted list of watches of a certain ebay listing.I figured out that the problem is this line:

```
entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0].watchCount[0]
```

because sometimes listing don't have any watches at all and in this case value watchCount doesn't exist at all so I can't loop through it, although I tried to use conditional operator (and if else statements in many different ways) it still throws an error.  First I created an object:

```js
watcherCount = () => {
    return (
         this.state.itemList.reduce((watcherObject,item) => {
             const watcherKey = item.itemId;
                 if (!watcherObject[watcherKey]) {
                     watcherObject[watcherKey] = [item];
                 } else {
                     watcherObject[watcherKey].push(item);
                     
                 }
             return watcherObject;
         },{})
         
     );
}
```

and now I am trying to move them to an array ([number of watches, title of listing, item id]) in order to sort them:

```js
import React from 'react';

    class Watches extends React.Component {
    
    render () {
    
        var entriesObj = Object.entries(this.props.watcherCount);
        var sortable = [];
        for (var value in entriesObj){
            for (var value in entriesObj){
                sortable.push([typeof entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0].watchCount[0] === "undefined" ? "-" : entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0].watchCount[0], entriesObj[value][1][0].title[0], entriesObj[value][0]]);
            }
         }

        sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b[0] - a[0];
         });
         console.log(sortable);
    //Output: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

        return <table></table>
     }
}

export default Watches;
```

Do you know any other way to build this exact kind of array or how to solve the problem with missing property?

Comment: `entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0].watchCount && entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0].watchCount[0]`

Comment: What is the structure of your data?

Comment: @hindmost it's not obvious. The error just says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". That error can be because this `entriesObj[value][1]` is undefined, or this `entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo` too.

Comment: @Karlen Kishmiryan entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo always exists (it has also few other properties), the problem is that it only sometimes has property watchCount[0], but not always - it depends if a listing has watches, if not, this property simply doesn't exist

Comment: @Natalia try this
`var listing = entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0];`
`var watches = (listing.watchCount && listing.watchCount[0]) || [];`

Comment: @Karlen Kishmiryan _it's not obvious._ You have to address this to the OP since she claims that the error's due to `watchCount` doesn't exist, not me.

Comment: @hindmost I just read the comment about the error in code.

Comment: @Karlen Kishmiryan it works now!!! thank you so much :)

Comment: @Natalia I'm glad I could help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if I fully understood the problem.

In cases with deep references, if I don't want or can't use any conditional checks I simply put the object path reference in a try catch (finally) block.

e.g. (untested though)

```
for (var value in entriesObj){
  var val;
  try {
    // just make sure the only error that might be occuring
    // here is an object reference error
    // therefore the array push happens after the try catch block
    val = entriesObj[value][1][0].listingInfo[0].watchCount[0], entriesObj[value][1][0].title[0], entriesObj[value][0]];
  } catch(err) {
    val = "-";
    // log the error or maybe issue a warning since missing items
    // is actually expected behaviour
  } finally {
    sortable.push(val);
  }
}
```

Maybe it solves your problem.